# Use optional cypher query results in subsequent query and combine results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a working cypher query to get optional results and then use the resulting nodes in a subsequent query and combine the result.

```
MATCH (n:KnowledgeEntry {id: 'd0634a24-91d0-4fd7-8868-2caa3ab0dc7a' })
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:IS_PART]->(p:KnowledgeEntry)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)<-[ch:IS_PART*1..2]-(d:HierarchicalKnowledgeEntry)
UNWIND d AS descendant
UNWIND p AS parent
UNWIND r AS parentRelation
UNWIND ch AS childRelation
WITH (collect(DISTINCT n) + collect(DISTINCT parent) + collect(DISTINCT descendant)) as  nodes, parentRelation, childRelation
UNWIND nodes AS n
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:CONTEXTUAL_KNOWLEDGE]-(c:ContextualKnowledgeEntry)
UNWIND nodes AS node
UNWIND c AS contextualNode
UNWIND r AS contextualRelation
WITH collect(DISTINCT node) + collect(DISTINCT contextualNode) as knowledgeEntries,
collect(distinct parentRelation) + collect(distinct childRelation) + collect(distinct contextualRelation) as edges
return knowledgeEntries, edges
```

It's a bit ugly and I'm asking myself if there is a better way to build this query.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding about UNWIND here. UNWIND is the opposite of collect(), it's meant to be used on lists, but the only things you unwound that were lists were `ch` and `nodes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As InverseFalcon said in the comment section, UNWIND is like a 'for loop' for of a list.  You can re-write your query as below.

```
MATCH (n:KnowledgeEntry {id: 'd0634a24-91d0-4fd7-8868-2caa3ab0dc7a' })
WITH n
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:IS_PART]->(p:KnowledgeEntry)
WITH n, p, r
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)<-[ch:IS_PART*1..2]-(d:HierarchicalKnowledgeEntry)
WITH n, p, d, r, ch
WITH (collect(DISTINCT n) + collect(DISTINCT p) + collect(DISTINCT d)) as  nodes, collect(DISTINCT r)  as parentRelation, collect(DISTINCT ch) as childRelation
UNWIND nodes AS n
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:CONTEXTUAL_KNOWLEDGE]-(c:ContextualKnowledgeEntry)
WITH n as node, parentRelation, childRelation, c AS contextualNode, r as contextualRelation
WITH collect(DISTINCT node) + collect(DISTINCT contextualNode) as knowledgeEntries, parentRelation + childRelation + collect(distinct contextualRelation) as edges
return knowledgeEntries, edges
```

Comment: Thank you! The only issue that remains is that the edges result is a multi-dimensional array instead of a flat array. Ist there a way to collect the relations without falling back to unwind?